# Where can I find information about how to implement Intel embedded AES256 encryption?

Tags: encryption, aes, x86

I heard this can really speed up encryption performance, but I can't find any good information about how to implement it.

Answer (score 6):

The [AES instruction set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) is supported by most modern compilers (gcc/g++ 4.4 or later, Visual Studio 2008 SP1 or later, Intel c/c++ compiler 11.1 or later).

For gcc, you'll have to use the -mtune with a supported [CPU type](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html), or the -maes switch.

It looks like the next generation Cryptography API for Windows (in Windows 7) supports AES-NI. So, if you are using the Crypto API in your code, that should automatically happen on supported machines.

Your other option is to use a precompiled library that has AES-NI support built in. Wikipedia has a list of [libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set#Software_supporting_AES_instruction_set).

Answer (score 0):

If they've released processors with it, the necessary registers and opcodes to use will be in the latest edition of the x86 architecture programming manuals on Intel's website [here](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html).
Exactly which manual it is in I do not know as I need to grab latest copies myself.